# Check if AlphaTest supported on a render system

Tags: rendering, ogre

I have an application using on multi-platform and I want to check whether current `render system` support `AlphaTest` or not, usign `Ogre`.
I couldn't find the argument I need to pass to `hasCapability`.
any help?

**CODE:**

```
const RenderSystemCapabilities *caps = Root::getSingleton().getRenderSystem()->getCapabilities();
bool AlphaTestSupport = caps->hasCapability(/*???*/);
```

Comment: This will not answer your question, but why are you interested in the fixed-function alpha test? The modern approach is to do this test yourself during your fragment/pixel shader and discard/clip the execution results if the test fails. That works all the way back to D3D9 and all the way forward to every modern API Ogre has a renderer for; whereas it is absent from D3D10+ or core GL3+.

Comment: The app is running also on old devices that use only FFP (no shaders) so then I use RTShader. but if I don't have to I prefer not to do this and use the built in AlphaTest. @AndonM.Coleman